# UNIX Shell scripting (digit based subtraction)?

Tags: shell, unix, date

I have an input like 2013_07_02 (It may be any date). I want to retrieve date which is 2 days back from the input date. How to do so?

Comment: This is more complex than subtracting digits .. and even more complex than the case presented .. what is two days back from `1988_03_01`? Now, I'm fairly certain there are some date-aware commands out there (and as a last resort, Perl or Python or whatnot might be useable), so I'd start looking at how to deal with it in terms of a "real" date type ..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In case you want the output in the same format as the input, i.e. `2013-07-02`, substitute `_` with `-` before passing to date:

```
$ inputdate='2013_07_02';
$ date --date=${mydate//_/-}'-2 day' +'%Y_%m_%d'
2013_06_30
```

Answer (score 2):

[`date`](http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?date) is your friend:

```
date -d "2013-01-01 -2 days" +"%Y-%m-%d"
```

This prints out `2012-12-30`.

Answer (score 2):

use `date` with `-d` option. It understands relative dates, even with common language like 
`date -d "two days ago"`.
In your case something like

```
  date -d "2013-07-01 -2 days"
```

would be enough.